# umbraco 7.2 on azure websites takes 1.5gb memory

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, umbraco7

I have a simple Umbraco 7.2 website (no plugins/custom code/etc) on a Shared Azure Website. Azure has suspended the website twice in the last week because of over quota memory usage. I scaled it up to 6 instances for now. Looking at the dashboard right now, it shows me it's using 1.5gigs. I went on the Kudu interface (.scm.azurewebsites.net) and in the Process Explorer it shows that the the process is only taking ~150mb of both `private memory` `and working set`. It also says `virtual memory` is taking ~750mb.

Why is Azure saying it's taking up so much memory? Does increasing instance count actually mean more memory for my app or does it just mean more instances are running the same app... so it's basically 200mb*6 instances = 1200megs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scale up the number of instances for an Azure Website it changes the number of VMs your website is running on - so it means more instances running the same app.

Similarly, when you log into the Kudu interface this is going to connect to the process running on one particular instance - so it won't show you total memory being used by all instances at once, just what's used by the one particular instance you're connected to.

Comment: thanks. thought so just couldn't find anything to confirm it. that explains the 1.5gig umbraco is using. I guess the only solution is the "Basic" plan. too pricy for a simple website.